# Why inner function in cycle has no the same lenght as outer function?

Tags: python, function, plot, scikit-learn

I coded own class SGDRegressor which inherits from sklearn.base.BaseEstimator. My method fit creates a variable w_ that stores the vector of weights for which the mean squared error (MSE) is minimal:

```
class SGDRegressor(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, 
                 w = None, 
                 n_iter = 1000,
                 eta=0.001,
                 mse_= None):
        self.w = w
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.eta = eta
        self.mse_= mse_
        
        self.w0_by_iter = []
        self.w1_by_iter = []
        self.mse_by_iter = []
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        global w_

        n, k = X.shape

        self.w = np.zeros(2)      

        for iter_num in range(self.n_iter):
            self.w[0] = self.w[0]-self.eta*2/n*(y[iter_num]-(self.w[0]+self.w[1])*X[iter_num])
            self.w[1] = self.w[1]-self.eta*2/n*(y[iter_num]-(self.w[0]+self.w[1])*X[iter_num])*X[iter_num]
            
            self.w0_by_iter.append(self.w[0])
            self.w1_by_iter.append(self.w[1])

            def mse(params):
                self.w[0], self.w[1] = params
                self.mse_ = np.sqrt(1/n*(y[iter_num]-(self.w[0]+self.w[1]*X[iter_num]))**2)
                self.mse_by_iter.append(self.mse_)
                return self.mse_
        
        result = optimize.minimize(mse, self.w, method = 'Nelder-Mead')
        w_ = result.x
        return w_, self
```

But I would like to clarify: when I plot mse by each iteration I have 10x less length (100 instead 1000) on xlabel [![result of plot][1]][1]:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6, 4)
plt.plot(range(len(myRegressor.mse_by_iter)), myRegressor.mse_by_iter);
plt.xlabel('# iter.')
plt.ylabel('MSE');
```

Anyway I thought that cycle's length is the same for all objects it contains, even inner function.

Can you please help me to make it the same for mse?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkSIw.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeatedly *redefine* the function `mse` in the loop, but that never actually adds to the array `mse_by_iter` until the function gets called by the `scipy` optimization.  So the length of the array is completely determined by `scipy`, not your `n_iter`.

Comment: so it is better to make mse_by_iter.append(mse(params))?

Comment: I didn't spend too much time trying to understand your code, but it strikes me that you're trying to optimize parameters twice: once with manual code and the loop, then again with scipy.  The `mse` function probably doesn't need to be a function, instead moving its logic into the loop?

Comment: i tried to make parametric function from mse